# createNamedQuery not return objects in the database even though there are

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a problem with the collection of objects from the database using createNamedQuery although they are there.

business class :

```
Article article;
        try{
            TypedQuery<Article> query = em.createNamedQuery("Article.findByTitle", Article.class);
            query.setParameter("articleTitle",title);
            article = query.getResultList().size()==1 ? query.getResultList().get(0) : null;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            throw new NoResultException();
        }
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQuery(name = "Article.findByTitle", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.articleTitle = :articleTitle")
public class Article implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(unique = true, name = "article_id")
    private Integer articleId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "article_title")
    private String articleTitle;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

in console is log this query:

```
INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) Hibernate: select article0_.article_id as article_1_0_, article0_.article_date as article_2_0_, article0_.article_short_content as article_3_0_, article0_.article_title as article_4_0_, article0_.article_url as article_5_0_ from article article0_ where article0_.article_title=?
```

Entitymanager work properly because performs persist or merger

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a debug. You have this line:

```
article = query.getResultList().size()==1 ? query.getResultList().get(0) : null;
```

Maybe you are getting more than one result on the query and if that happens that line of code makes article null. 
You can try also:

```
List<Article> articles;
        try{
            TypedQuery<Article> query = em.createNamedQuery("Article.findByTitle", Article.class);
            query.setParameter("articleTitle",title);
            articles = query.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            throw new NoResultException();
        }
```

getResultList() return a list of objects and because you have TypedQuery you can initialize has List of Article